# Can I get Java 5 to ignore @Override errors?

Tags: java, annotations, overriding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does Eclipse complain about @Override on interface methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987973/why-does-eclipse-complain-about-override-on-interface-methods)

I have some Java code that was written using Eclipse and the Java 6 SDK, so methods that implement an interface are annotated with `@Override` - an annotation that is legal in Java 6, but not in Java 5.

I'd like to compile the same code using the Java 5 SDK (`javac` on Mac OS X 10.5). Everything compiles and runs fine except for the `@Override` annotations. Is there any way I can get javac to ignore the `@Override` annotations for this project, or is the only solution to remove them all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently you can upgrade to Java 1.5 u21 and this will fix the problem:

[Why is javac failing on @Override annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335655/why-is-javac-failing-on-override-annotation)

Comment: I read that question and all it's answers, and it's not confirmed for JDK 1.5u21 and 1.5u22, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335655/why-is-javac-failing-on-override-annotation#comment3379487_2335752

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, the only way is to actually remove the annotations.

If you do want to have your code compile and run with Java 5, you should develop targeting Java 5.  Otherwise, you might accidentally rely on a Java 6 specific SDK methods and such.

Comment: One could easily remove them via a pre-processing step however.

Answer (score 2):

You can use JDK6 to compile 1.5 code. Use `-bootclasspath`, `-target`, and `-source`. Alternatively, I believe the Eclipse compiler treats `@Override` the same (this might be wrong!).

1.5 has finished its End of Service Life period, and I suggest letting it rot.

Comment: +1 For suggesting -target and -source. Would be interesting to see if this works.

Comment: Does this work, did you try it? ^^

Answer (score -1):

@Override is valid in java 5 -> http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/Override.html

I recommend that you check your project's compiler settings in Eclipse, perhaps at Project -> Compiler -> Error/Warnings -> Annotations?

Comment: +1 - I was going to say the same thing.  I use @Override too and I'm still on jdk 1.5.

Comment: @Override's semantics changed bwetween Java 5 and 6 - in 5, it caused a compiler error when used on a method implementing an interface. In 6, it causes a warning when *not* used on such a method. The question is about how to deal with this difference.

Comment: Yes @Override is valid in Java 5. But the specification has changed for Java6. In Java6, you can know annotate methods that implement methods of an interface. This was not possible in Java6.

Comment: "Indicates that a method declaration is intended to override a method declaration in a superclass" -- method-method override is supported, but method-interface override is not! (Or someone please correct me)

Comment: It is as I wrote: method-interface override is supported since Java 6, but unfortunately this change is not documented anywhere (I believe there's an official bug concerning the API doc not being updated).

Comment: One of a number of bugs on this issue: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=5008260

Answer (score -1):

Java 6 is available for OS X.  Check software update.  When you have it, set it to be the default java version, and then compile.

Comment: That's not really a solution when he wants to target Java 5 as well.