# Java Comparator class to sort arrays

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, comparator

Say, we have the following 2-dimensional array:

```
int camels[][] = new int[n][2];
```

How should Java `Comparator` class be declared to sort the arrays by their first elements in decreasing order using `Arrays.sort(camels, comparator)`? The `compare` function for reference is:

```
@Override public int compare(int[] a, int [] b)
{
    return b[0] - a[0];
}
```

Answer (score 111, accepted):

> *[...] How should Java Comparator class be declared to sort the arrays by their **first elements in decreasing order** [...]*

Here's a complete example using **Java 8**:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int[][] twoDim = { {1, 2}, {3, 7}, {8, 9}, {4, 2}, {5, 3} };

        Arrays.sort(twoDim, Comparator.comparingInt(a -> a[0])
                                      .reversed());

        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(twoDim));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[[8, 9], [5, 3], [4, 2], [3, 7], [1, 2]]
```

---

For **Java 7** you can do:

```
Arrays.sort(twoDim, new Comparator<int[]>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(int[] o1, int[] o2) {
        return Integer.compare(o2[0], o1[0]);
    }
});
```

---

If you unfortunate enough to work on **Java 6** or older, you'd do:

```
Arrays.sort(twoDim, new Comparator<int[]>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(int[] o1, int[] o2) {
        return ((Integer) o2[0]).compareTo(o1[0]);
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry to bring up an old thread but why was there a need to cast to Integer when you return the compare method?

Comment: @EvolutionaryHigh, because you can't call `.compareTo` on an `int`.

Comment: Also the @Override annotation won't work in java 5. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987973/why-does-eclipse-complain-about-override-on-interface-methods

Comment: Oh gosh. Such small use case that have evolved in from 4, to 5, to 6, to 7, to 8 :-) Kind of interesting.

Comment: I think closure in Swift may refer to this to make its own format, e.g. `sort() {$1 > $2}`, all about anonymous function.

Comment: What should I add in the above code if I want to sort this 2d array in increasing order of the first element and if the first elements of two 1 d arrays are same the sort them according to the second element?

Comment: This solution is not compiling anymore in Java 17… still figuring it out how to do binary search, but for sorting you can just stream it and box the int to Integer before sorting

Comment: @FrancescoGabbrielli, I haven't tested the snippets in Java 17, but I doubt that it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 11):

Just tried this solution, we don't have to even write int.

```
int[][] twoDim = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 7 }, { 8, 9 }, { 4, 2 }, { 5, 3 } };
Arrays.sort(twoDim, (a1,a2) -> a2[0] - a1[0]);
```

This thing will also work, it automatically detects the type of string.

Answer (score 10):

The answer from @aioobe is excellent. I just want to add another way for Java 8.

```
int[][] twoDim = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 7 }, { 8, 9 }, { 4, 2 }, { 5, 3 } };

Arrays.sort(twoDim, (int[] o1, int[] o2) -> o2[0] - o1[0]);

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(twoDim));
```

For me it's intuitive and easy to remember with Java 8 syntax.

Answer (score 0):

`java.nio.IntBuffer#wrap(int[])` provides an excellent built-in way to compare two instances of `int[]`, since `IntBuffer` is both a lightweight wrapper for `int[]` instances, *and* implements `Comparable`.  Using it combined with other built-in `Comparator` features has several advantages over the examples in other answers I see here:

- Compares all sub-array elements
- Supports variable sub-array lengths
- Supports `null` array elements

This example sorts the arrays in descending order, putting `null` array elements last:

```
int[][] twoDim = {{1, 2}, {3, 7}, {8, 9}, {4, 2}, null, {5, 3}, {4}};
System.out.println("Unsorted: " + Arrays.deepToString(twoDim));

Comparator<int[]> c = Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.comparing(IntBuffer::wrap));
Arrays.sort(twoDim, c.reversed());
System.out.println("Sorted: " + Arrays.deepToString(twoDim));
```

Output:

```
Unsorted: [[1, 2], [3, 7], [8, 9], [4, 2], null, [5, 3], [4]]
Sorted: [[8, 9], [5, 3], [4, 2], [4], [3, 7], [1, 2], null]
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's sorting Arraylist of Date Arrays.
Maybe smb smwhen will need it.

```java
List <Date[]> sortedDateList = new ArrayList<>(/* initialization */);
Collections.sort(sortedDateList, new Comparator<Date[]>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Date[] d1, Date[] d2) {
        return (d1[0].compareTo(d2[0]));
    }
});
```