# Move part of array to the front in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array similar to that:

```
[null, null, 3, 4, null]
```

I want to change it to array similar to that:

```
[3, 4, null, null, null]
```

I know how to do it manually, but it looks ugly.
Is there any **built-in**(with minimum custom code) way to do that? (maybe something with System.arraycopy)

I finished with something like this(thanks @Braj for idea):

```
@Test
public void test() {
  Integer[] k = new Integer[]{null, null, 3, 2, 1};
  k[1] = null;
  Arrays.sort(k, new Comparator<Object>() {
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
      System.out.println(o1);
      if (o1 == null) return 1;
      else if(o2 == null) return -1;
      else return 0;
    }
  });
  assertArrayEquals(
    new Integer[]{3, 2, 1, null, null},
    k
  );
}
```

If somebody interested there is [a bigger problem which tried to solve with this code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/56193/queue-over-resizable-array-implementation)

Comment: Please include the code you have tried.

Comment: Do you care about the ordering of non-null elements? Should they be sorted in any specific way? Should they retain their initial order?

Comment: Yes, they should retain their initial order

Comment: 1) It looks ugly --> put that ugly code in a method, and you no longer have to see that ugly code (abstraction). As for using the API, there is a `java.util.Arrays`. If it is not there, you will waste more time searching for a solution than solving it yourself

Comment: You can take a look at Guava and its [`nullsLast`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html) ordering. I'm not sure you can use it without sorting the collection in any way at the same time so it may not be that concise a solution.

Comment: If somebody interested there is a [bigger problem](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/56193/queue-over-resizable-array-implementation) which I tried to solve with this code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Arrays.sort(T[],Comparator)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator)) and pass Comparator to sort based on your own logic.

Read more here and find sample code as well

- [Java Comparator class to sort arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393254/java-comparator-class-to-sort-arrays)
- [How to sort an array of ints using a custom comparator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699141/how-to-sort-an-array-of-ints-using-a-custom-comparator)

---

Here is the sample code that sorts the array as well while pushing `null` values in the end.

Note: (*change it as per your need, not fully tested*)

```
    final Integer[] data = new Integer[] { null, null, 3, 4, null };
    Arrays.sort(data, new Comparator<Integer>() {
        public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
            if(o1 != null && o2!=null){
                return o1.compareTo(o2);
            }else if(o2 != null){
                return o2;
            }else{                  
                return Integer.MIN_VALUE; // null values in the end
            }
        }
    });

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
```

output:

```
   [3, 4, null, null, null]
```

---

#### EDIT

If you are interested only in moving the `null` values in the end then find sample code in the below post that is answered by @Dmitry Ginzburg

Comment: on `[null, null, 4, 3, null]` this code would return `[3, 4, null, null, null]`, which is incorrect.

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg what is expected?

Comment: @Braj `[4, 3, null, null, null]`

Comment: @Braj I adopted your solution a little bit. Can you check it(now it's a part of question)?

Comment: @kharandziuk use `Comparator<Integer>` instead of `Comparator<Object>`

Comment: @kharandziuk I tested your code and it result into incorrect output.  input `[null, null, 3, 4, 2, null]` and output `[3, 4, 2, null, null, null]`

Comment: @Braj, What is the reason to do that? I chose Integer type just for example

Comment: @kharandziuk I am using`Integer#compareTo()` method inside `Comparator` and there is no meaning of comparing Dog with Cat or String with Integer. That's why make it more generic.

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg What OP says in the post at line 3 and 4. *I want to change it to array similar to that:*`[3, 4, null, null, null]`

Comment: @Braj about >I tested your code. It's a correct behavior)

Comment: @kharandziuk Time to leave. Change the code as per your need.

Comment: @Braj, I've changed the input array a little bit, so you should look at it more careful.

Answer (score 2):

The `sort` algo from Java standard library is stable, so, if we're making the elements, which are not null the same (in the context of ordering), it would keep the order:

```
Arrays.sort(data, new Comparator<Integer>() {
    public int compare (Integer x1, Integer x2) {
        if (x1 == null && x2 != null)
            return 1;
        else if (x1 != null && x2 == null)
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
});
```

Comment: Incorrect result. I tested your code for input `[null, null, 3, 4, 2, null]` and output `[3, 4, 2, null, null, null]`

Comment: Your code is correct, but Braj provided an idea earlier. Thanks!

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg Sorry I have taken it in wrong way. I was thinking from sorting perspective as well. As per sorting logic it should be []2, 3, 4, null, null, null] but I was wrong. I think OP just want to move the items and not interested in sorting.

Comment: @Braj, yep, it's really what OP requesting.