# How do i put my array in alphabetical order?

Tags: java, arrays

I am having trouble figuring out how to put the `String[][]` store array in alphabetical order looking at the second column which consist of gifts, school supplies textbooks, and campus gear.
I would very much appreciate the help.

**

```
 String[][] store = {       
            {"Alumni Drink ware", "Gifts", "$25.00"},  
            {"Binders", "School Supplies", "$3.00"},  
            {"Book bag", "School Supplies", "$20.00"},  
            {"Fabulous Desserts", "Textbooks", "$25.00"},  
            {"Folders", "School Supplies", "$1.00"},  
            {"Gift Cards", "Gifts", "$25.00"},  
            {"Highlighters", "School Supplies", "$2.00"},  
            {"Jacket", "Campus Gear", "$65.00"},  
            {"JAVA Programming", "Textbooks", "$150.00"},  
            {"Network Solutions", "Textbooks", "$75.00"},  
            {"Pencils", "School Supplies", "$1.00"},  
            {"Pens", "School Supplies", "$2.00"},  
            {"Shorts", "Campus Gear", "$10.00"},  
            {"Sweatshirts", "Campus Gear", "$40.00"},  
            {"T-shirts", "campus Gear", "$15.00"},  
            {"Web Design Ideas", "Textbooks", "$55.00"}};
```

**this is how my array looks when I display it. I'm trying to sort the second column or use that to sort the array. **

```
   Alumni Drink ware                   Gifts                  $25.00    
             Binders         School Supplies                   $3.00    
            Book bag         School Supplies                  $20.00    
   Fabulous Desserts               Textbooks                  $25.00    
             Folders         School Supplies                   $1.00    
          Gift Cards                   Gifts                  $25.00    
        Highlighters         School Supplies                   $2.00    
              Jacket             Campus Gear                  $65.00    
    JAVA Programming               Textbooks                 $150.00    
   Network Solutions               Textbooks                  $75.00    
             Pencils         School Supplies                   $1.00    
                Pens         School Supplies                   $2.00    
              Shorts             Campus Gear                  $10.00    
         Sweatshirts             Campus Gear                  $40.00    
            T-shirts             campus Gear                  $15.00    
    Web Design Ideas               Textbooks                  $55.00
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393254/java-comparator-class-to-sort-arrays

Comment: What kind of array this?

Comment: Tyr it like this `Arrays.sort(store, Comparator.comparing((String[] arr) -> arr[1]));`, based on the link from @user3707125

Comment: How would I use a comparator class to work for me I keep getting the syntax wrong or it just doesn't compile. I have never used a comparator so I don't know how its supposed to look for my string array I just keep finding examples for Integers

Comment: Thanks I'm going to try it now

Comment: Thanks @SubOptimal it worked.