# How to let my output be decreasing and increasing order in digit(java)

Tags: java, for-loop

If i input 1324,3591

It mean i want the bigger denote in order.

```
int x = 1324;
int y = 3591;
System.out.println(x+y);

I want the output show:
```

4321 and 8531

Comment: Please show us some code you are trying.

Comment: Store them in an array, and sort them.

Comment: can you get me an example :

Comment: How in the earth is this list `1234,1235,1589,1457,1489` be increasing ??? And `4321,5321,9851,7541,9841` be decreasing ??

Comment: i want the digits in order

Comment: when i use this code, it was let the number in order: system.out.println("The decreasing order:");
for (int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
   
    System.out.printf(array[i]);
System.out.println();

Comment: So your INPUT is those ones not the output right ? Edit your question with your code

Comment: I think we all misunderstood you. We thought you wanted to have your *numbers* decreasing and increasing (i.e. the elements of the array in a specific order), but what you want is **per** number sort the digits, right? In your example, each array item is sorted, and not the array itself.

Comment: so how to do per number sort the digits

Comment: @kappa I can show you the entire codes, but it seems that you don't really like to accept solutions.

Comment: @user3437460  can you how me the entire codes

Answer (score 1):

Create two function, `public int[] orderAsIncreasing(int input[])` and `public int[] orderAsDecreasing(int input[])`.

Then, loop inside the input searching for the highest value, and place it as the first/last in the output of each function. Remove that value from the array. Repeat until the array is empty. Then return the result

I will not post code, since this looks like some sort of homework. The logic is there. Now, use google and documentations to get the operators for it.

Comment: but i use :Random r = new Random();
        
   int x = r.nextInt(9999)+1;    the input should be random number

Comment: then change to what you need... `public int orderAsIncreasing(int input)`. Done. just `int s = orderAsIncreasing(r);`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should convert the numbers to strings and then to char arrays. If 'number' is your number, then something like:

```
String numberAsString = String.valueOf(number);
char[] charArray = numberAsString.toCharArray();
Arrays.sort(charArray);
String newNumberAsString = new String(charArray);
int number2= Integer.valueOf(newNumberAsString);
```

Comment: String numberAsString = String.valueOf(array);
char[] charArray = numberAsString.toCharArray();

// in reverse order
Arrays.sort(array);
System.out.println(Arrays.asList());

System.out.println("The decreasing order:");
for (int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
   
    System.out.printf(String.format("%04d ", numberAsString);
System.out.println();       it can't run

Comment: I have added some more code to make my point clear. If you need reverse order, you must sort with a different comparator.

Comment: if i want to being a decreasing order for 1325 out 5321 what should i do

Comment: You have to implement your own comparator. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393254/java-comparator-class-to-sort-arrays