# How to do per number sort the digits (java)

Tags: java, arrays

If i input 1324,3591

It mean i want the bigger denote in order.

```
int x = 1324;
int y = 3591;
System.out.println(x+y);

I want the output show:
```

4321 and 8531

```
int num = x; 
char[] digits = Integer.toString(num).toCharArray();
Arrays.sort(digits); 


 System.out.println(digits);
      }
```

but i want use %04d to make output be 4 digit but if i change to prinf it can't run....

Comment: Printing the sum wouldn't print that anyways.

Comment: You asked [this **same** question yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33943843/how-to-let-my-output-be-decreasing-and-increasing-order-in-digitjava). Please don't do duplicates of your questions! Instead *edit* your original question!

Answer (score 0):

You could just sort the number based on their digits.

```
int num = 1234; //suppose.
char[] digits = (""+num).toCharArray();
Arrays.sort(digits);
System.out.println(new StringBuilder().append(digits).reverse());
```

Comment: error on the System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(new String(digits));