# Java - Find Minimum and Maximum value of an array of Strings

Tags: java, arrays

I'm new to programming in java. The below source code is found in a book, when i try to execute the program it is showing some incorrect data.

```
public class Pair<T> {

    private T first;
    private T second;

    public Pair() {
        first = null;
        second = null;
    }

    public Pair(T first, T second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    public T getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public T getSecond() {
        return second;
    }

    public void setFirst(T newValue) {
        first = newValue;
    }

    public void setSecond(T newValue) {
        second = newValue;
    }  
}
```

Logic to find the min and max value of the string array

```
public class ArrayAlg {

    public static Pair<String> minmax(String[] arr) {
        if (arr == null || arr.length == 0)
            return null;

        String min = arr[0];
        String max = arr[0];

        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (min.compareTo(arr[i]) > 0)
                min = arr[i];
            if (max.compareTo(arr[i]) < 0)
                max = arr[i];
        }
        return new Pair<String>(min, max);

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] words = { "Mary", "had", "a", "little", "lamb" };
        Pair<String> obj = ArrayAlg.minmax(words);
        System.out.println("Minvalue " + obj.getFirst());
        System.out.println("Maxvalue " + obj.getSecond());

    }
```

If you execute the above program, it displays `Minvalue = Mary and MaxValue = little`. The value `a` in the String array is the Minimum Value but in this case it is showing `Mary` as the Min Value.
Can anyone tell me the better approach to find the Minimum and Maximum value in the String array?

Answer (score 3):

The output you got is the correct output, since the natural ordering of Strings is lexicographical order, in which upper case letters come before lower case letters. Hence `Mary` is the "smallest" String.

In order not to use the natural ordering, don't use `String`'s `compareTo` method. Instead you can implement whatever logic you see fit to determine which String is smaller. One way of introducing alternative ordering is passing a `Comparator<String>` instance to your `minmax` method and using its `compare` method to compare the `String`s.

Comment: Why not help by showing a readily available comparator for the purpose: `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`. Or `Collator.getInstance()`?

Comment: @Andreas I'm not sure what the desired ordering was. It's possible that the only problem with the output was the case sensitive ordering, but I can't be sure of that.

Comment: Since there's very high probability that is exactly what OP needs, you should suggest it, rather than (or in addition to) only saying *"implement whatever logic you see fit"*, implying that OP would have to write the `Comparator` from scratch. That's not very useful.

Answer (score 3):

I think, for you purposes it's better to use `String` method `compareToIgnoreCase()`.

But it depends on you understanding what does `Minimum string` and `Maximum string` is.

Also, there is preffered way to compare any objects - via `Comparator`.

```
public static Pair<String> minmax(String[] arr) {
    if (arr == null || arr.length == 0)
        return null;

    Arrays.sort(arr, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return o1.compareToIgnoreCase(o2); // to compare by lexicographical order
            //return o1.length() - o2.lenth(); // to compare by length
        }
    });

    return new Pair<String>(arr[0], arr[arr.length - 1]);
}
```

Here are some links to follow:

- [Java Comparator class to sort arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393254/java-comparator-class-to-sort-arrays)
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html
- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_comparator.htm

Comment: can u please modify the code and update based on the question posted above

Comment: I dunno how to modify,

Comment: @Aishu, I modified as little to fit you code with minimum changes.

Comment: Why not use the freely available `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` comparator, rather than creating your own doing the same thing? Also, sorting the entire array has two problems: 1) It modifies the array, which may not be appropriate. 2) It's slower than just finding min/max.

Comment: @ar4ers - May I know what is the output u r getting?

Comment: String[] words = { "mary", "had", "a", "little", "lamb" }; - This is my  string array

Comment: As per ur logic the output is Minvalue =  a
Maxvalue = mary

Comment: but Max Value should be little not marry

Comment: @Aishu okay, I don't understand your sort logic. But I tried to show you the common method of solving this kind of problems. So you can do it by yourself :-)

Comment: @Aishu why `little` should be the `max`? In the lexicographical order `l` is above `m`.

Comment: yeah, as i already mentioned, this example is taken from the book, So i thought of asking an alternative from u guys

Comment: the value "little" has the highest length in the string array, that's y

Comment: @Aishu then just replace `o1.compareToIgnoreCase(o2)` with `o1.length() - o2.length()`

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use a `Comparator` for this. You can sort the words alphabetically, ignoring case, by using the `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` `Comparator`.

In Java 8 this can be achieved easily using Lambdas:

```
public final Pair<String> miniMax(final String[] words) {
    final String min = Arrays.stream(words).min(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER).orElse(null);
    final String max = Arrays.stream(words).max(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER).orElse(null);
    return new Pair<>(min, max);
}
```

Testing:

```
String[] words = { "Mary", "had", "a", "little", "lamb" };
System.out.println(miniMax(words));
```

Output:

```
a, Mary
```

Answer (score 1):

[`compareTo()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)) compares the strings lexicographically, meaning that uppercase letters come before lowercase letters, since that is the order in [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Latin_(Unicode_block)#Compact_table). Instead, do one of the following:

- Use [`compareToIgnoreCase()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase(java.lang.String))
- Use a case-insensitive [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), readily available from [`String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)
- Use a full language-specific `Comparator`, that will order special characters and international letters like you would see in a book index, available from [`Collator.getInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html#getInstance())

Alternatively, for a good Java 8 implementation, see [answer by arizzle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38120105/5221149).

So, your loop could be:

```
for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (min.compareToIgnoreCase(arr[i]) > 0)
        min = arr[i];
    if (max.compareToIgnoreCase(arr[i]) < 0)
        max = arr[i];
}
```

Or:

```
Comparator<String> comp = Collator.getInstance();
for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (comp.compare(min, arr[i]) > 0)
        min = arr[i];
    if (comp.compare(max, arr[i]) < 0)
        max = arr[i];
}
```