# sort item in fragment by ID from json

Tags: java, android, json

hey i want to sort item from the new to the old by id from json
i want the new item to apear on the top of the list 
i am using this code

```
try {
    JSONObject mainJson = new JSONObject(result);
    JSONArray jsonArray = mainJson.getJSONArray(Constant.ARRAY_NAME);
    JSONObject objJson = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length();  i++) {
        objJson = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

        ItemWallpaper objItem = new ItemWallpaper();

        objItem.setWallId(objJson.getString(Constant.WALL_ID));
        objItem.setWallImage(objJson.getString(Constant.WALL_IMAGE));

        arrayOfLatestImage.add(objItem);
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

for(int j=0;j<arrayOfLatestImage.size(); j++)
{
    objAllBean=arrayOfLatestImage.get(j);

    allListImage.add(objAllBean.getWallImage());
    allArrayImage=allListImage.toArray(allArrayImage);

    allListId.add(objAllBean.getWallId());
    allArrayId=allListId.toArray(allArrayId);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand your code. But i assume you just want the `arrayOfLatestImage` sorted by the wallId of the ItemWallpaper objects.

The keyword you are looking for is "comperator" in java.
small example taken from [Java Comparator class to sort arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393254/java-comparator-class-to-sort-arrays)

```
Arrays.sort(twoDim, new Comparator<int[]>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(int[] o1, int[] o2) {
      return ((Integer) o2[0]).compareTo(o1[0]);
  }
});
```

Check here for more information
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Comment: sorry for the short code i will try to word on this

Answer (score 0):

Just write an own comparator which compares the `ItemWallpaper` objects. Check this link for more info: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Comparator.html