# How to use Java Comparator to sort an array of arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, comparator

The problem is to sort an array of two element arrays based on the absolute difference of the elements of those inner arrays in descending order, so `{{1, 3}, {4, 12}, {5, 8}` would be sorted as `{{4, 12}, {5, 8}, {1, 3}}`

I have code like this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[][] arr = {{1, 3}, {3, 12}, {12, 16}};

        Arrays.sort(arr, Comparator.comparing(arr, (Integer[] a, Integer[] b) -> a[1] + b[1] - a[0] - b[0]);
    }
}
```

but I get this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nvj72.png). It says "cannot infer functional interface type".

Edit: upon changing the above to

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[][] arr = {{1, 3}, {3, 12}, {12, 16}};

        Arrays.sort(arr, Comparator.comparing(a -> a[0] - a[1]));

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
            System.out.print("{" + arr[i][0] + ", " + arr[i][1] + "}, ");
        }
    }
}
```

I get the desired output, but I was unable to get the reversed() method to work like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393254/java-comparator-class-to-sort-arrays). I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZDGd.png) error where it says "Array type expected; found: 'java.lang.Object'"

I suppose my question is mostly answered but if someone could clarify the issue with reversed I'd appreciate it.

Edit: and sorry, I neglected to use Math.abs() as in the context of my problem I know the array is always increasing like {2,3}, {3,6}, {6,8}... etc

Comment: Please read the Javadoc for `Comparator.comparing` and edit your question to explain why you think the parameters you are passing to it are correct, or to ask a question about what parameters it accepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descending:

```
Arrays.sort(arr, (o1, o2) -> Math.abs(o2[0] - o2[1]) - Math.abs(o1[0] - o1[1]));
```

Ascending:

```
Arrays.sort(arr, Comparator.comparingInt(o -> Math.abs(o[0] - o[1])));
```