# Compiling java 7 for java 6 with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation, java-7, java-6

I need to compile a project for Java 6 to use with java 6 or 7 (I can't upgrade all of the computers in my life). I've been searching all over and found somewhat [helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869869/is-there-a-java-7-to-java-6-converter) [stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661980/compiling-java-7-to-java-6), but I'm rather new to java - I don't understand much of how to use the presented alternatives (ant-build, Maven, javac).

My program does not use any API methods that are not available in Java 6, but it does use the API of another external .JAR (it is a basic plugin for an example program)

Is there a simple way to do this with Eclipse's Export function, or do I need to use some other program/method?

If I need to use something other than Eclipse, how would I best go about doing it for a multi-class, multi-package file dependent on another external .jar's API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click on your project in eclipse and open the `project properties`.

Then navigate to `Java compiler` and set the compliance level to 1.6.

[image]

That should do it.

Comment: Thanks so much to both of you! I feel stupid for not realizing something so simple, but I couldn't find it anywhere >.<

Comment: Aah, accepted. I had tried to upvote, but I don't have 15 rep.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse Juno SR1: 
right click your project -> Properties -> Java Compiler -> Compiler compliance level.

Set that to 1.6 and you're done. You might need to enable project specific settings and disable compliance with execution environment - 2 checkboxes in the same window.