# The method must override or implement a superclass method

Tags: java, eclipse, interface, implementation, superclass

Quick question.  I am using Eclipse and I am getting the The method must override or implement a superclass method error, except Eclipse is using compliance of Java 1.7.
Here is my Code:

```
public abstract class M4 implements Armory {

@Override
public Integer weaponAmmo(int wepAmmo) {
    wepAmmo = 10;
    return wepAmmo;
}

@Override
public Integer weaponDamage(int wepDamage) {
    wepDamage = 2;
    return wepDamage;
}

@Override
public String weaponName(String wepName) {
    wepName = "M4";
    return wepName;
}
```

And here is the interface Code:

```
public interface Armory {
        public Integer weaponAmmo(int wepAmmo);
        public Integer weaponDamage(int wepDamage);
        public String weaponName(String wepName);

    }
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678122/must-override-a-superclass-method-errors-after-importing-a-project-into-eclips

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to use `@override` annotation in your method implementation as you are not overriding the methods. **You are just implementing the interface methods. This annotation is required when your override any super class methods.**

Remove the `@Override` annotations and it should be fine.

Comment: Question is why its not asking for java 1.7 in eclipse

Comment: Ah, Got it! For some reason whenever I saved, eclipse would stick those back in as if I needed them. I turned that off and deleted the annotations so It's all good now, thanks!

Comment: @ShandanSpencer If you think it's helpful then don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: @ShandanSpencer I would suggest you to get them (annotations) back. These annotations give the compiler more control over your code during refactoring.

Answer (score 2):

In Java 5 `@Override` was allowed only for methods overriding super class methods. Since Java 6 `@Override` is also allowed for methods implementing interface methods.

Answer (score 1):

You are not overriding anything, you are implementing them . So i guess @Override can be removed.

EDIT: I think your compiler is set to Java 1.5 in eclipse

[Why does Eclipse complain about @Override on interface methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987973/why-does-eclipse-complain-about-override-on-interface-methods)

@override on interface implementations are allowed from java 1.6 onwards.

Answer (score 0):

Even if Eclipse has been set to compliance level higher than Java 1.5 this error may occur because of Project properties as in your case. Right click on your Project > Properties > Java Compiler. Change it to 1.6 or higher here too. Do Project > Clean.