# Eclipse - I have Java 1.6 set in my Window-Preferences, but the compiler is giving errors about the @Override

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Would anyone know why this happens? I seem to have Java 1.6 set, but I still get the `@Override` errors as though the system thinks I am on 1.5 which is strange.

Any thoughts on why this happens?

**EDIT**

The error message is

> The method `method(parametertypes)` of type `Type` must override a
>   superclass method

Comment: Override? or _o_verride?

Comment: Can you post some more details about the errors? Also, I think the annotation is `@Override` (not `@override`)

Comment: The @Override that you put in front of a method name :)

Comment: Check if this helps:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987973/why-does-eclipse-complain-about-override-on-interface-methods

Comment: Check the project settings: Java Build Path, Java Compiler.

Comment: @Genadinik with _more details_ I mean **exact error message**.

Comment: @jlordo here is an example of the error message: The method getSkuDetails(int, String, String, Bundle) of type IInAppBillingService.Stub.Proxy must override a superclass method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set both the compliance level

[image]

and add the appropriate JRE library (right-click the project and select "properties" to get the screen below)

[image]

You may need to "clean" the project (Project > Clean...)  after completing the above steps.

Comment: thanks, I set the first screen as you have it. But how do I navigate to the second screen you posted?

Comment: Thank you ....Under build paths I have only Android libraries. From which directory should I add the jre?

Comment: the thing is that I do not have a JRE library in there.  Which jar exactly do I need to add? Could you please outline the steps so I do not mess it up :)

Comment: Oh, you're developing an Android application? I'm not experienced with Android. However, I believe the required runtime is already included in the Android libraries themselves. So setting the compliance level should suffice.

Comment: Ok seemed to have worked by the way :) ....fingers crossed and once again thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already, navigate to <kbd>Window</kbd> -> <kbd>Preferences</kbd> -> <kbd>Java</kbd> -> <kbd>Compiler</kbd> and set the Compiler compliance level to 1.6.

This assumes that you've already set 1.6 on the project's build path.

Comment: how do I make sure that I set the build path to 1.6?