# Jetty Websocket Compilation Errors

Tags: websocket, jetty

I am trying to do an Jetty  Web Socket example .
I copied a example from internet , which was working fine when i deployed directly  into server without making any chnages .

But when i copied the Source (the servlet) into Eclipse IDE , it was giving Compilation 
Exceptions related to

```
 The method onClose(int, String) of type Html5Servlet.StockTickerSocket must override a superclass method

- The method onOpen(WebSocket.Connection) of type Html5Servlet.StockTickerSocket must override a superclass method

The method onMessage(String) of type Html5Servlet.StockTickerSocket must override a superclass method
```

This is my servlet , i kept the jars as it is mentioned in that example

```
package org.ajeesh.app;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocket;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketServlet;

public class Html5Servlet extends WebSocketServlet {


    private AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger();

    private static final List<String> tickers = new ArrayList<String>();
    static{
        tickers.add("ajeesh");
        tickers.add("peeyu");
        tickers.add("kidillan");
        tickers.add("entammo");
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public WebSocket doWebSocketConnect(HttpServletRequest req, String resp) {
        System.out.println("On server");
        return new StockTickerSocket();
    }
    protected String getMyJsonTicker(){
        StringBuilder start=new StringBuilder("{");
        start.append("\"stocks\":[");
        int counter=0;
        for (String aTicker : tickers) {
            counter++;

            start.append("{ \"ticker\":\""+aTicker +"\""+","+"\"price\":\""+index.incrementAndGet()+"\" }");
            if(counter<tickers.size()){
                start.append(",");
            }
        }
        start.append("]");
        start.append("}");
        return start.toString();
    }
    public class StockTickerSocket implements WebSocket.OnTextMessage{
        private Connection connection;
        private Timer timer; 


        @Override
        public void onClose(int arg0, String arg1) {
            System.out.println("Web socket closed!");
        }

        @Override
        public void onOpen(Connection connection) {
            System.out.println("onOpen!");
            this.connection=connection;
            this.timer=new Timer();
        }

        @Override
        public void onMessage(String data) {
            System.out.println("onMessage!");   
            if(data.indexOf("disconnect")>=0){
                connection.close();
                timer.cancel();
            }else{
                sendMessage();

            }           
        }

        private void sendMessage() {
            System.out.println("sendMessage!");         
            if(connection==null||!connection.isOpen()){
                System.out.println("Connection is closed!!");
                return;
            }
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try{
                            System.out.println("Running task");
                            connection.sendMessage(getMyJsonTicker());
                        }
                        catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Date(),5000);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of jetty?

Comment: See old answer about @Override and java interfaces: 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/987992/775715