# Won't let me override interface method

Tags: java

I have an interface which has a `OnTaskComplete` which takes in a string method and within my class I have

```
public class JSONActivity extends Activity implements OnRetrieveHttpData
```

`OnRetrieveHttpData` being my interface however when I try to override it, it comes back with an error saying

The method `onTaskCompleted(String)` of type `JSONActivity` must override a superclass method

here is the code within my class

```
public class JSONActivity extends Activity implements OnRetrieveHttpData {
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_json);
 }

 @Override
public void onTaskCompleted(String twitterData) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

}

and here is my code within the interface

```
public interface OnRetrieveHttpData {
    void onTaskCompleted(String twitterData);
}
```

Comment: Show us your full code.

Comment: The error suggests that the signatures in the interface and your class aren't *exactly* the same.

Comment: ok I will edit my post to include more code

Comment: Is this because your method has a lower case o?

Comment: @BenGreen methods starting with lower-case conform to Java coding style standard, so I highly doubt this is the reason. It would be weird if it started with an upper-case letter.

Comment: @m0skit0 Sorry for the confusion. I am aware that this is convention, I was just trying to point out that according to the question, the method has an uppercase O in the interface and in the concrete implementation it is lower case.

Comment: @BenGreen Oh ok, didn't see that :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using jdk1.5, switch over to jdk 1.6.

In 1.5 you can't use @override for interface methods while in 1.6 you can. This is the issue you are facing.

Comment: Also you cant change the visibility modifiers.

Comment: how do you switch over to jdk 1.6?

Comment: Download jdk 1.6 setup :). And compile and run your code against jdk1.6.

Comment: ahh how do you check which JDK you have?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987973/why-does-eclipse-complain-about-override-on-interface-methods

Comment: I just checked in Eclipse that my JDK is 1.7

Comment: @DorkMonstuh Your project must also be configured to use Java 1.6+ syntax.

Comment: I downvoted but only because I read too quickly and did not see "for interface methods". This answer is correct.

Comment: @DaveNewton How do you do that?

Comment: @DorkMonstuh right-clic your project, select "properties", and check "Java Compiler" and "Java Build Path".