# Intellij Override warnings

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm having an annoying issue with IntelliJ where it's putting yellow warning lines under my @Override annotations when implementing an interface?

[image]

Any ideas why?

Cheers.

EDIT: Error reads "'@Override not applicable to method'".

Interface decleration:

```
public interface Material {

public long getID();

public String getMaterialCode();

public String getMaterialShortName();

public String getMaterialLongName();
```

}

class deceleration:

```
public class StandardMaterial implements Material {

private long id;
private String materialCode;
private String materialShortName;
private String materialLongName;

public long getID() {
    return id;
}

@Override
public String getMaterialCode() {
    return materialCode;
}

@Override
public String getMaterialShortName() {
    return materialShortName;
}

@Override
public String getMaterialLongName() {
    return materialLongName;
}
```

}

(Using Java 8)

[image]

Comment: what is intellij message when put mouse on @override? intellij does not show unnecessary errors. it should be a problem in your code

Comment: Is your project set to Java 1.5 compatibility, by any chance?

Comment: what message it shows on mouse hover on `@Override` ?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I'm using language level 7.0

Comment: @NimChimpsky Already using java 8!

Comment: @Ash um, I bet your not. Are you sure intellij is using the correct compiler

Comment: @BlueOcean updated to show error

Comment: This is already asked, check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987973/why-does-eclipse-complain-about-override-on-interface-methods. If you have the language level of the project set to Java 1.8 (which is not showing in the screen shot, but rather only the SDK version), and still get this problem, make sure that your module are configured to use the project-language-level (Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S), and do not override it with something like 1.5.

Comment: I've set the language level to 7.0 for both the project and the two mobile inside the project. I've also changed maven to use java 1.8 jdk, but im still getting the issue.

Answer (score 3):

If it is a maven project, make sure that you have a definition for the maven-compiler-plugin in your pom.xml where you explicitely set the compile and source level to at least 1.6.

For example:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
</plugin>
```

It defaults to 1.5 so @Override is not available yet. Intellij Idea seems to evaluate the compiler plugin even if it's not specified.

Answer (score 1):

Override annotation for interfaces is only supported with java 6 and higher.

Check intellij is using the correct jdk and language level, and also maven (or whatever build tool you use outside of intellij). Check you have not overridden the project sdk for this particualr module.

Answer (score 0):

Do not write your methods manually. Could you create only a `StandardMaterial` class that implements a `Material` interface, and then `ctrl + space` to generate implemented methods automatically? Also, your `getID` method does not have an override annotation.