# How should I handle my @Override Errors

Tags: java, javacc

I am using java tree builder and JavaCC to make my own coding language. However, my eclipse is unhappy with the  generated `jtb` code having `@Override` is this sence:

```
@Override
public <R, A> R accept(final IRetArguVisitor<R, A> vis, final A argu) {
  return vis.visit(this, argu);
}
```

The error says

Multiple markers at this line

- The method accept(IRetArguVisitor, A) of type

  AdditiveExpression must override a superclass method
- implements EMSL.syntaxtree.INode.accept

Should I delete all the `@Override` Methods or what should I do to fix these errors? (And yes, all the errors have to do with the override)

Comment: What is your Java version ?

Comment: Is that method actually overriding something?  Seems like maybe this is a `jtb` issue?

Comment: I am using JDK version 1.5 and my Eclipse offered to delete the `@Override` method and that does remove the error

Comment: Should I delete the `@Override`s?

Comment: Why are you using version 1.5? Do you enjoy antiques?

Comment: Try with JDK 1.6+. Maybe it's because @Override in interfaces is available only since 1.6.

Comment: If it helps the tree is generated by jtb 1.4.10

Comment: oh and `@Override` is in the java version I am using, I think it might just be a bug in the generating of the code. I am making sure I can delete the `@Override`s without messing everything up. (is it overriding the already present statements with the new code language?)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987973/why-does-eclipse-complain-about-override-on-interface-methods