# @override behaving weirdly

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc

It might be a basic question, but I am not able to figure out the issue.

I have an interface and a class as following:

```
public interface AssetService {
    List<City> findById(String id);
}

@Service
@Transactional
public class AssetServiceImpl implements AssetService {

    @Autowired
    private CityRepository cityRepository;


    @Override
    public List<City> findById(String id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

In the above class when I auto create unimplemented methods from eclipse, it gave the method alone with out any errors, when I add @Override manually it throws the following error:

The method findById(String) of type AssetServiceImpl must override a superclass method.

Ideally, as I am Overriding the method it should indicate that same. Am I doing some this wrong ?

I am using Spring Boot

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Which version of jdk do you use?

Comment: I am using jdk 1.8

Comment: Got the solution, its actually Project compliance issue. Eclipse accepts @Override from java 6. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987973/why-does-eclipse-complain-about-override-on-interface-methods

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between adding method manually and by eclipse. Please clean the project and see.